# How to reduce the incoming bandwidth?

Tags: google-app-engine, quota

We have a small application that was use mostly as an API. It's basically **an image extractor**. You submit a url to it, and it will return its largest image url. Feel free to [check the source code](https://github.com/superfeedr/image-extrator).

It runs smoothly, except that we bump into the *incoming bandwidth* limit quite frequently". What's odd, is that there shouldn't be that much incoming bandwidth.
For example, today, we received `64,308 requests` and `we consumed 1.00 GBytes of the incoming bandwidth`. All the other quotas are in the green.

We're looking for ways to debug this, and hopefully ways to reduce that. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#UrlFetch), the response of URLfetch counts towards the incoming bandwidth quota. So if you have 65k requests per day you will certainly hit that limit if you are downloading images for each one of those.

Comment: Indeed :(  What I quite don't grok is why they put a limit on incoming bandwitdh, when said bandwidth is actually free when going beyond the "free" quota: http://cloud.google.com/pricing/

Comment: But for that you need to have enabled billing, and it has a minimum of $2.10/week.